# WIX removes folder from WOW6432Node

Tags: wix, registry

I want to delete folder "TestCom" from HKLM\Software:

```
<RemoveRegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\TestCom" Action="removeOnUninstall" />
```

But when I unistall application, it deletes TestCom folder from SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\TestCom.

How can I remove SOFTWARE\TestCom folder ?

Answer (score 2):

With just what is shown in the question, it's reasonable to assume this is either a 32-bit package, or at least a RemoveRegistryKey tied to a 32-bit component. In either of those cases, it will use a 32-bit view of the system.

My favorite way to visualize this is to launch **c:\windows\syswow64\regedit.exe** and view the registry through this 32-bit application. In that view, you will see that HKLM\SOFTWARE\TestCom is what has been modified.

Comment: Great tip to remember